# How about adding a {bib-segmenting} (or, more generally, {segmenting}) tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Currently, there aren't many "sub-tags" in the [bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibliographies) tag area -- there's [citing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citing) and [sorting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting), and there are the "package" tags like [biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex) and [natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natbib) (which nowadays are used without adding [bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibliographies)).

From my experience, there are more and more questions about multiple and/or subdivided bibliographies, and these questions are hard to find among the many hundred bibliography questions (which contributes to new duplicate questions). Therefore, I suggest to create a [bib-segmenting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bib-segmenting) tag and to add it to the appropriate questions (slowly and starting with the highest-scoring ones). As an alternative, one could choose a general name ([segmenting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/segmenting)) for the new tag so that it could be used for the (few) questions about multiple/subdivided indexes and glossaries as well.

Note: I wouldn't use [sectioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sectioning) to mark the questions at hand because this tag is traditionally about tinkering with `\chapter`, `\section` & friends, which requires a different kind of expertise.

EDIT: Inspired by barbara beeton's comments, I'm leaning towards a general tag called [subdividing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subdividing).

Comment: there *is* a tag `[multibib]` but that is specific to a package. maybe `[multiple-bibliographies]'?  (i'm not sure if there's a length limitation to tag names.)  i'd find the term "multiple" more intuitive that "segmenting", since sometimes separate bibliographies are wanted per-chapter, and "segmenting" implies dividing up a single element.

Comment: @barbarabeeton One could choose {multiple-biblio} or {multiple-bibs}. Do you perhaps also have a suggestion for a "geneneral" tag name?

Comment: "subdividing" is the best i can think of now.  a trip to a thesaurus offers "partitioning", but i think that has technical connotations that are misleading.  (totally inappropriate are "mangling", "dismemberment", "dissociation", ..., but i always get distracted when i visit a thesaurus; you're guilty of encouraging a devout word freak.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton {subdividing} is pretty good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have started to add the [subdividing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subdividing) tag to appropriate questions. I also created a tag wiki excerpt:

> [subdividing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subdividing) is about multiple/subdivided [bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibliographies),
>   indexes or similar document elements. If you use this tag, add the
>   appropriate general tag or preferably the tag of the specific package
>   you use (e.g., [biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblatex)).

UPDATE: Retagging has been completed; right now, 103 questions feature the [subdividing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subdividing) tag.